# Titanium, actionBar icon not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

```
if(Alloy.Globals.isAndroid){//if platform is android
  $.tabGroup.addEventListener("open", function(e) {

    var activity = $.tabGroup.getActivity();// I use tabgroup. get activity

    var actionBar = activity.actionBar;
    actionBar.icon =Ti.App.Android.R.drawable.logo;//this code not working

    activity.onCreateOptionsMenu = function(e) {
        var menuItem = e.menu.add({
            title : "Refresh",
            showAsAction : Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS,
            icon:  Titanium.App.Android.R.drawable.ic_action_refresh //this code working right
        });
        menuItem.addEventListener("click", refreshMain);
    };
    activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();


  });
}
```

I want set actionBar icon. Menu item icon is working right but actionBar icon not working. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Soner,

Did you solve this issue ?

Comment: Yep. I solved this issue

Comment: I created folders like "res-hdpi","res-ldpi" under the android root folder (assets/android/res-hdpi). And I put my icons there.

actionBar.icon = "/images/logo.png" // and it is working :)

Comment: Hi Soner,

did you also manage to display both an icon and a title in the same menu item ? If I set I title, like in your example, the icon is not displaying anymore..